# Chrome tabs query returning empty tab array

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to port a Web Extension that I've gotten working in Firefox to chrome and I having some problems. I need to send a message form the background script to a content script. I was using a port when I first build it from Firefox, but I switched it to using `chrome.tabs.query()` because chrome kept finding an error. But now with `query()`, it still works fine in Firefox, but now chrome is saying that it can't find the current tab:

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://hhfioopideeaaehgbpehkmjjhghmaaha/DubedAniDL_background.js:169:11
```

It returns that the tab argument pass is length == 0. `console.log(tabs)`:

```
[]
```

This is the function that Chrome is complaining about.

```js
var browser = chrome; // I set this only for compatibility with chrome; not set in Firefox.

function sendToTab(thing) {
    browser.tabs.query(
    {active: true, currentWindow: true},
    function(tabs) {
        console.log(tabs);
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(
            tabs[0].id, // The inspector identifies an error on this line
            thing
        );
    }
    );
}
```

The same function works fine in Firefox and has no problem getting access to the tab. But it doesn't work in Chrome.

### Update 2020-01-30

@wOxxOm:

> Show the code that calls sendToTab

This is where sendToTab is called:

```js
function logURL(requestDetails) {
    var l = requestDetails.url;
    if (l.includes(test_url)) {
        if (logOn) { console.log(l); }
        sendToTab({dl_url: l});
    }
}


browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    logURL,
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

Comment: @wOxxOm I have both open. I tried with all dev stuff closed and just the page the extension is supposed to run on and still I have a problem. After reloading, the extension still isn't communicating correctly. I think I have to restructure the scripts so the content script always initiates contact with the background.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just added the sendToTab to the question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like you're running this code while your active window is devtools, which is a [known bug](https://crbug.com/462939).

Another problem takes place in *your code*: it always accesses the focused (active) tab even though the request may have occurred in a backgrounded (inactive) tab.

**Solution:**

Use the tab id provided inside the listener [function parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) as `tabId` property.
In your case it's `requestDetails.tabId`

If for whatever reason you really want the active tab, make sure a real window is active while this code runs or use the following workaround that succeeds even if devtools window is focused:

```js
chrome.windows.getCurrent(w => {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: w.id}, tabs => {
    const tabId = tabs[0].id;
    // use tabId here...
  });
});
```