# chrome.tabs.query was used, so that i could grab links from the current tab, which is a feature needed for a extension i am making

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, parameters

//the html is below

```
     <button id="tab-el">SAVE TAB</button>
```

//the javascript is below

```
tabEl.addEventListener("click", function(){  
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        myLeads.push(tabs[0].url)
        localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads) )
        render(myLeads)
    })
})
```

//the JSON file is below

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "Leads tracker",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
        "permissions": [
          "tabs"
        ]
      
}
```

//the error my chrome console is showing is below

```
Script.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Script.js:51:17)
```

//tired to grab links from websites to create a bookmark extension
but so far not working

Comment: Did you open index.html directly from disk or from localhost? It won't work. Open it by clicking your extension icon. Note that this popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: thank you so much for helping. yes i tried what u have suggested,

Comment: thank you so much for helping. yes i tried what u have suggested, when i try to grab the url using the extension it doent work. and the dev tools of the extension says,....Array(1)
0 : {active: true, audible: false, autoDiscardable: true, discarded: false, favIconUrl: '', …}
length : 1
[[Prototype]] : Array(0)

Comment: Add "activeTab" to "permissions" and use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63886442)

Comment: Thank you a lot. My problem is solved. you were a great help.